# ¿Cómo ordenar las columnas de una tabla generada con table()?

Tags: r

Con la función `table()` creo una tabla de contingencia, pero está me saca las columnas desordenadas, ¿hay alguna forma de ordenarlas? Por ejemplo el orden es una escala likert pero está escala me salen en desorden.

Answer (score 2):

`table()` espera un objeto de entrada que pueda ser tratado como un factor, por lo que podrías alimentar la función directamente con un `factor` con el orden en particular que desees, simplemente definiendo el mismo mediante el parámetro `levels`:

```
set.seed(1)
l <- letters[1:3]
# Orden de las columnas por defecto: alfabético ascendente
table(l, sample(l))

l   a b c
  a 1 0 0
  b 0 0 1
  c 0 1 0

# Modificamos el orden de las columnas
# (descendente)
l <- factor(letters[1:3], levels=letters[3:1])
table(l, sample(l))

l   c b a
  c 0 1 0
  b 0 0 1
  a 1 0 0
```

Si tienes la suerte que las variables ya sean un `factor` puedes reordenar las mismas de forma similar:

```
casos <- factor(sample(letters[1:3]))
# casos ya es un factor, lo reeordenamos descendente
casos <-factor(casos, levels=letters[3:1])

table(letters[1:3], casos)
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, este método no se ve afectado sí previamente ten las variables convertidas a factor ??

Comment: No, si tienes un variable que ya es `factor`, puedes reordenarla de forma similar `var_factor <- factor(var_vactor, levels=vector_ordenado)`